# JPA: Repeated attempt to create a query fails

Tags: java, jpa, orm, transactions, eclipselink

In a Java SE application using EclipseLink 2.0 some data is updated in a database using the following method:

```
public void updateDepartment(int from, int to) {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    List<String> uuidList = getEmployeeUuids(from);

    entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Employee SET department = :department WHERE uuid IN :uuidList")
            .setParameter("uuidList", uuidList)
            .setParameter("department", to)
            .executeUpdate();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Everything works as expected. Immediately after that, another query is created that reads some data from the database using the same `entityManager`.

Finally the application calls the `updateDeparment(int from, int to)` method again. Only this time it cannot create the query, outputting the following warning:

```
The class RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork is already flushing. The query will be 
executed without further changes being written to the database.  If the query
is conditional upon changed data the changes may not be reflected in the results. 
Users should issue a flush() call upon completion of the dependent changes and 
prior to this flush() to ensure correct results.
```

Subsequently the database doesn't get updated.

I haven't found any other mention of this warning on the web.

Debugging the application I've noticed that excluding the code that reads data from the database between two calls of `updateDeparment(int from, int to)` method solves the problem. But I cannot see what causes this behavior and what exactly EclipseLink warning is complaining about.

Comment: I've never seen this, does it occur in a later EclipseLink version as well?

Comment: That was it. With the latest version of EL it works like a charm.